# Java or C++: Send current to USB when sound plays

Tags: java, c++

Is there a way in java, or even C++, to send current depending on how much sound is playing?
Let's say, if there is a lot of sound playing, the USB port will be receiving 20mA, and if there is very little sound, the USB port will receive 5mA, and if there is no sound, obviously 0 current / voltage. You don't have to go too in depth with your response. Just maybe point me in the right direction and help me get started.
I do prefer java over C++, that would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: No, I've looked around a bit, but haven't found any information. I do home some experience with java though, and have written a few Android applications.

Comment: Have you found information about USB communication? Have you found information about checking what sound is playing?

Comment: What OS? I have solution for Win, maybe for linux also.But keep in mind that USB is not AD/DC converter.You can power up port or not.If there is 'inteligent' device on port it can specify how much power it needs.You can not  avoid this.

Comment: OS would be Windows 7. Now, 6747467454, what you mean is ta USB port can only haev 5.00Vdc +/- .25V or 0, and you can't specify the current sent to the USB port through code?

Comment: *"send current depending on how much sound is playing?"*  What application feature is that intended to support?  To notify someone of a comment, add the `@` symbol before the name, like @6747467454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This in the proposed form is not doable. The power supply is either turned on, or off, but not in between. without hardware you can not make a LED sound meter out of it...

However, it would be fairly easy to accomplish this using commercially available, USB ready building blocks. There are multiple options, but I'd prefer an Arduino. Connected to the USB port, it can be connected as if it was a serial port, and that is nőt very difficult to do. For this, you need these to be done:

- get an Arduino
- write a sketch in C that accepts your input, lets say ASCII encoded decimal integer values, and does the function you want, like power a LED through PWM pin with variable duty cycle (Arduino side)
- write your code, that acquires whatever you need ("how much sound is splayed", whhatever that means...), on the PC side, in whatever language you prefer
- send the numeric values to the Arduino using serial port communication from the PC side code

Answer (score 1):

No. The hardware does not support this functionality. The USB port is not a DAC.

Comment: And besides, normal DACs prdouce voltages, not currents.

Answer (score 1):

i think both are good, unless you know the concept the language u going into.
but still, i'll prefer java beacuse of simple coding.
you can use sequencer or **mixer** and can send it to the port you want.
mixer can handle sending/reciving multiple midi events.
but in java , sound API is not much advance, but in c++ u can use
python's large liabrary,which can help you to get the frequency
or voltage.where as in java,functions are limited,
and at time's you need to add external liabrary or preform
FFt(i hate this part).
that's it! good luck